# QwtScaleWidget::getBorderDistHint() returns wrong border distance

Tags: c++, qt, qwt, qt5.15

I create a timeline widget based on QwtScaleWidget to render it in an image. If I don't show this widget `widget.show()`, the method QwtScaleWidget::getBorderDistHint() returns wrong border distance. Maybe you have some idea why it occurs?

Comment: I expect you will have to debug with the qwt source code to see.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.